# Setting up vnc server and no physical display : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: unity, 16.04, vnc, xserver, display-manager

I am trying to setup a vnc server on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS which has unity desktop installed. I do not want to install other desktop environment.

I installed `x11vncserver` and later realized that it does not work when the server does not have a physical monitor. It gives the error as

```
*** XOpenDisplay failed. No -display or DISPLAY.
```

(There are ways to emulate the monitor but I did not try it.)

After removing it, I tried `vncserver` ( [xvnc](http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/vnc_docs/xvnc.html) ) 
which does work but I need to move to gnome panel and it looks really weird and low quality.

Connection details: Gigabit ethernet (all the way from client to server) but not on local network.

Can somebody help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foremost, install `x11vnc`:

```
sudo apt install x11vnc -y
```

To create the password, run the following command (please do not use 12345678).

```
sudo x11vnc -storepasswd 12345678 /etc/x11vnc.pass
```

To secure the password, run the commands:

```
$ sudo chmod 744 /etc/x11vnc.pass
$ sudo chattr +i /etc/x11vnc.pass
```

Edit and append to the bottom of `lightdm` configuration file as such:

```
sudo vi /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add:

```
# vnc server configuration. This is one big line.

[SeatDefaults]
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -xkb -nowcr -repeat -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass  -forever -bg -rfbport 5900 -scale 1270x710 -o /var/log/x11vnc.log
```

Restart lightdm

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Make sure x11vnc is running

```
pgrep x11vnc
```

From the connecting computer, do this,

```
sudo apt-get install xtightvncviewer -y
vncviewer
```

Enter the IP Address of x11vnc server and connect.

*Please do not use 12345678 as password.*

Comment: I will try it and let you know if it works.

Comment: `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` does not exist on my system. Inside `/etc/lightdm` I have `users.conf` and an empty folder as `lightdm.conf.d`

Comment: You can create /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf if if doesn't exist.

Comment: I did exactly  as mentioned and after restarting the `lightdm` service, I find that the `x11vnc` service is not running. Also checked that no service is listening on the specified port (5901 for my case). I cannot restart the server since production work is running. What  can I try.

Comment: Well, you've made a mistake somewhere... This configuration works on Ubuntu 14.04 all the way to 16.10.

Comment: Ok, I checked it with other PC. Your answer works. Thanks. I will format your answer a little.

Comment: x11vnc is not secure by default. I hope you tcwrap x11vnc if you're using it in a production environment as you stated, use iptables firewalls, and enable SSL with the -ssl. Then use ssvnc to connect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49195/discussion-between-dev-null-and-ankit7540).

Comment: How to Enable SSL for X11VNC? Can I access it using web browser. If yes..what are the steps to access it using web browser.  do i need to  enable additional plugins?